# Pokemon's distribution details on map

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

An NPC at the Tide Song hotel says if I zoom in on the map that I can find "details about a Pokemon's distribution" but if I zoom in I don't see anything.

Comment: Well, that's clearly not true. What Pokémon have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is available from the Pokédex's Location tab in a Pokémon's entry. In addition to showing which route or area a Pokémon is found in, by zooming in you can see which specific grass patches the Pokémon is in, or whether it's found by surfing or fishing.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but you beat me to it. [Here](https://daily.pokecommunity.com/2016/06/02/analysing-the-new-sun-moon-features/)'s the site I was going to use, it has a helpful picture :)